# Why can my device through PLEX only play one of these two 4K files?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, playback, plex, x265

I have two 4K `.mkvs` consisting of both video and audio tracks - my device seems to be able to play 4K content just fine for a movie, but won't playback upscaled 120 fps content. Both videos are `x265` and the main thing I seem to be able to pinpoint would be the fps causing trouble or perhaps the encoder being v1.4.4 vs the movie one being v.1.4.5. Could anybody help me out from the `ffprobe` info?

[Movie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4Ge4.png)

[Upscaled content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WbwM.png)

Comment: Are you certain your device supports 120fps video?

Comment: @Mokubai That's the thing - I can't seem to find it in the specifications here: https://www.lg.com/uk/tvs-soundbars/smart-tvs/43um7100plb/

Comment: The specification is right there: *4K@60p, 10bit*

Comment: @ChanganAuto Sorry, I had no idea 60p meant to be frames - I am quite new in the whole mediasphere with conversion and suiting content to my likes. Thanks for the pointer!